# How can I get my phantomjs test to send me images when it errors out on Travis?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, travis-ci

I have the following test which I use as part of my integration test for my Django application. It's a selenium test using PhantomJS as the driver:

```
import unittest
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class TestClaimsLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.ip = os.environ.get('DOCKER_IP', '172.17.0.1')

    def test_verify_main_screen_loaded(self):
        url = 'http://%s/eclaim/login/' % self.ip
        print url
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_user_name').send_keys("implementer")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_password').send_keys("eclaim_implementer")
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary').click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        greeting = self.driver.find_element_by_id("user-greeting")
        self.assertTrue(greeting.is_displayed())
        self.assertTrue('Hello, Implementer' in greeting.text)
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.driver.execute_script("set_language('ms')")
        sleep(5)
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.find_element_by_id("logo").text,
                         u'Staff Claims')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.get('http://%s/eclaim/logout' % self.ip)
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

This test runs in Travis and sometimes it will error out. My question is how can I get my test to send the screen capture image when it errors out ?

Answer (score 0):

Travis has `after_success` and `after_failure` build lifecycle steps which can be used to run commands after the `script` step has run and either failed or passed.

You could for example write a shell script which packages up your screen captures and secure copies them somewhere, or emails them, or uploads them to S3 or Dropbox.

See the [build lifecycle documentation here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle).